# use moment to get total days from array of dates

Tags: momentjs

Looking for some time now, but can't find anything. 
My question is. Can you get total of days from an array of dates using momentjs?

Or find gaps between those dates?

Comment: Can you add some details? Which is your input? Which is your desired output? What did you try so far?

Comment: Just checking the doc and google. If can't be done most likely I will write some helper.